# EasyAdminBundle + FOSUserBundle user management

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, easyadmin

I am doing a back office under symfony and easy admin bundle and FOSUserBundle. I would like to know if it was possible when the admin connects in his space, he sees only the normal users, which do not have the role admin only.
or separate administrators from normal users.

I ask the question because using Sonata I know it's possible, but since I have to do it under easyadmin I do not know if it's feasible.

I have been trying to do this for a while now and I would like to know if it was possible.

Merci d'avance :)

Answer (score 0):

In easy admin bundle you can filter entities with a DQL FILTER see the [documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#filtering-entities)

You can use this for dislplaying only normal users.

you can try this filter:

`dql_filter: "entity.roles NOT LIKE '%%env(ROLE_ADMIN)%%'"`

as you seem to be French-speaking, here is a very interesting [article about easyadminbundle](https://afsy.fr/avent/2017/01-easyadminbundle-l-arriere-guichet-easy-peasy)